# Fetching VB Variables to insert with SQL Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

Hello everybody hope you are well.

I have a place on a project im working on that im struggling to get past. I'm basically gathering meta data of a song and assigning them to variables in VB.

I'm next trying to save this data to a SQL database with tables i have created in visual studio and im having trouble doing this. The problem lies within trying to link the VB variables into a SQL query. Any Ideas?

Comment: We would need to see the code to have any ideas on what can go wrong.

Comment: Read up on ADO.NET, which is the standard .NET data access technology.  There's loads of information around on the subject.  If you have a specific issue then we need specific details of that issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To link VB variables to an SQL query, you need to add parameters that store the variables and then use those parameters in your SQL command:

**Using parameters**

```
MyCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Height, Weight, DoB, Gender, FROM `User` WHERE Username = @Username", DatabaseConnection)

MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username)
```

UPDATE: **How to connect to database**

```
'Leads to the database
Public Filename As String = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}YourDatabase.accdb"
'The connection string is set
Public ConStr As String = $"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA Source = {Filename}"
'The connection to the database is defined
Public DatabaseConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)
```

Comment: NO! Do not concatenate strings to build SQL queries. Use parameters or risk SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you, you no longer need the $ for an interpolated string. I will delete my comments in a few minutes.

Comment: "Not advised" is [quite an understatement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683). Please remove that section entirely.

Comment: What do you mean by "Databaseconnection", is that the dataset connected to my database? or a table adapter. Either way im struggling to get this to work.

Comment: @Lupe_99 Your question was not related to connecting to the database but putting VB variables into SQL. I will update my answer to include your update

Comment: Returns this error- Error 1 Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.